# How do I send a request using Guzzle?

Tags: php, request, guzzle6

When I send the request, there should have been authorization with the transition to the page. But it just updates and shows only the page in the authorization "https://passport.yandex.ru/auth". 
Request Headers

```
GET /php/guzzle/test.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cookie: _ym_uid=1523438286675328097; _ym_visorc_784657=b; _ym_isad=2
```

My code on PHP

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$base_url = 'https://passport.yandex.ru/auth?retpath=https%3A%2F%2Fzen.yandex.ru%2Fmedia%2Fzen%2Flogin';
$client =  new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$jar = new \GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar();
$res = $client->request(
    'GET',
    [
        'auth' =>
        [
            'login', 
            'pass'
        ],
        ['cookies' => $jar],
        ['allow_redirects' => true]
    ]
);
$res->getStatusCode();
$response = $res->getBody();

echo $res->getStatusCode();
// 200
echo $res->getHeaderLine('content-type');
// 'application/json; charset=utf8'
echo $res->getBody();
// '{"id": 1420053, "name": "guzzle", ...}'
```

How do I send the correct request for authorization with guzzle?

Comment: I hope for your understanding, the documentation looked.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make sense:

```
['cookies' => $jar],
['allow_redirects' => true]
```

Try this:

```
$res = $client->request(
    'GET',
    [
        'auth' =>
        [
            'login', 
            'pass'
        ],
        'cookies' => $jar,
        'allow_redirects' => true
    ]
);
```